# How can I install a kitchen drawer with only one side and no front beam?

Tags: drawers

I've got a set of IKEA cabinets that have a place for a drawer that's currently just a cover:

[image]

I'd like to install a drawer here, but there's only a full cabinet wall on the right side. The left is open, and goes deep to the left:

[image]

The top surface there seems to be the underside of the granite countertops, so I don't think I can mount anything directly into there?

In addition, there's no support beam across the middle in the front where a bottom drawer support might go:

[image]

My question is, **what are my reasonable options here for installing a drawer here**? I imagine any of them would involve adding at least one piece of wood for support, but I'm not sure where would provide the best support for the weight of a drawer. I see a few options:

1. Install a piece of wood along the side, from front beam to back wall.
2. Install a piece of wood across the front middle, between the left beam and right wall. Then install wood from the front to back for support.

That said, I've never done something like this before, so there may be more options. In addition to where to add support, what would be the proper method to install these additional pieces of wood? Screws? Brackets?

Comment: My first stop would be asking IKEA directly! They'll know what's available based on the cabinet better than anyone on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undermounts are the standard of the industry these days and most models don't require a side wall to support the drawer. Here's a [pdf](http://www.accuride.com/Resources/PDF/3132-r9-1107_.pdf) from Accuride that shows the rear hook you'll need (See page 3, figure 9), although Blum, Hettich, etc. all have there own version. The drawer will have to be made to the specs of the slides you purchase which will mean some rather serious woodworking, a pre-built [drawer](http://www.drawer.com/market/drawers/basic-custom-drawers?drawer_species=21&material_category=121&order=price) from a supplier, or you can get a drawer system like [this](http://www.cabinetparts.com/c/drawer-slides-metal-drawer-systems#loaded). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Top mount drawer slides are an option.

Comment: I've Googled around for these at your suggestion, but don't see them anywhere. Do you have any examples of what these might look like, how they work, and where they can be purchased?

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=top+mount+drawer+slides Click on "images for top mount drawer slides". Click on an image. Click on "visit page"...for me, the first image takes me to Amazon.